# Discord.js / Mute everyone

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I wrote the following code that is supposed to mute all the members in a given channel:

```
client.on('message', message => {
     if (message.content == 'sh!') {
         let channel = message.member.voice.channel
         for (let member of channel.members) {
             member[1].setMute(true)
         }
     }
})
```

But it does not work and I cannot find out why because I do not really know how the setMute() function works.

EDIT: I am not sure about how I can access every member and mute it

Comment: Why `member[1].setMute(true)` and not `member.setMute(true)`?

Comment: `let channel = message.member.voice.channel.members` why are you calling this `channel` when it is really the collection of the channel members? And then iterating over `channel.members` also seems wrong, since I don't think the collection has an extra `members` property

Comment: somehow not adding the members property makes it not iterable. anyways I am new to Discord.js and the StackOverview answers are apparently outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'setMute' function is part of the member's voice state object. You're using it directly from the GuildMember object itself. As you may already know, the voice state object is the property 'voice' of the GuildMember object. So here's the solution:

```
// change this
member[1].setMute(true);
// to this
member[1].voice.setMute(true);
```

The property Members of a VoiceChannel is a Discord Collection (which extends from Javascript Map), I would iterate using a forEach loop so I could avoid Downlevel Iteration.

This should work:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content == 'sh!') {
    const members = message.member.voice.channel.members;

    members.forEach(member => {
      member.voice.setMute(true);
    });
  }
});
```

Here's some useful links:
[TextChannel#members | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=members)
[Collection | discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)
[Map - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)